# Which kids movie, from the 80s involved aliens with guns that could be powered by pennies?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recall that when I was a kid in the late-80s/early-90s, my Dad rented a film for my brother and I.

The main character of the story was a boy, who had a big pit behind his house.  One night, he awoke to see a huge alien space ship landing in the pit.  Other details of the plot are rather vague, but here are some of the details that I can recall.

- The aliens were hostile, and I think they were abducting people/eating them.
- The boy couldn't convince anyone that he was seeing these monsters and that they were the cause of the abductions.
- As is usually the case, I think he had a teacher or some other older person who somewhat believed in him and aided him.
- The kid had a penny collection, and at some point he figured out that the alien weapons could be powered by inserting pennies.  This was a key plot point that helped him defeat the aliens.
- I seem to recall that the boy, some how defeated the aliens and the ending of the story is as such:

> The boy defeats the aliens and then awakens to find that it was all a dream.  After which, he notices that there is a big storm outside, and he runs to his parents bedroom.  When he opens the door, he sees aliens in the room, which have presumably eaten his parents, and the film ends.

I remember seeing this movie only one other time after my initial viewing.  It was aired on cable TV and since then I haven't heard about it.  Although I only saw it a couple times, I remember being quite fond of it and I'd like to see it again.  Does anyone recall which film this might be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may be the 1986 movie [Invaders From Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_%281986_film%29).

The synopsis mentions aliens landing in a familys backyard and people being abducted, but only a school nurse believing the child who knows about the aliens.

> In the end, the boy realizes that everything thus far had been a dream.

The synopsis does *not* mention the pennies, but another person searching for [a movie with a similar description (including the pennies)](http://www.killermovies.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-17094-need-name-of-80s-movie.html) confirmed that it was Invaders From Mars.

Comment: I can tell by the poster, that is it!  Next stop, check and see if it's on Netflix!  Thank you very much.